# Why outer join query not working?

Tags: sql, join

Hallo,
my objective is to generate a table that shows the total of each CODE that belong to the owner, take note that each owner must have a CODE tied to it no matter the TOTAL value is zero. So there will be APP, REJ, CAN tied to each of the APPROVAL_ID.

```
APPROVAL_ID  CODE  TOTAL
-----------  ----  -----
101          APP   2
101          REJ   1
101          CAN   3
102          APP   2
102          REJ   4
102          CAN   0
103          APP   0
103          REJ   0
103          CAN   4
```

Thus, here is the source code:

```
select approval_id, code, total
from (
  select 'APP' code, '1' seq from dual
  union all
  select 'REJ' code, '2' seq from dual
  union all
  select 'CAN' code, '3' seq from dual
)
left outer join (
      select m.approval_id, own.name, m.decision, count(*) total, 
      case own.channel
          when 'CH1' then 'CH1'
          when 'CH2' then 'CH2'
          else 'Others Channel'
      end the_channel
      from tableM m, owner own
      where m.decision in ('REJ', 'APP', 'CAN')
      and own.id=m.approval_id
      group by m.approval_id, own.name, m.decision, own.channel
      order by m.approval_id
)
on code=decision
group by approval_id, code, total
order by approval_id;
```

The output from the above query is like below:

```
APPROVAL_ID  CODE  TOTAL
-----------  ----  -----
101          APP   2
101          REJ   1
101          CAN   3
102          APP   2
102          REJ   4
103          CAN   4
```

The output of the inner query is like below:

```
APPROVAL_ID  CODE  TOTAL
-----------  ----  -----
101          APP   2
101          REJ   1
101          CAN   3
102          APP   2
102          REJ   4
103          CAN   4
```

Something was not right to the query because I know that some of the row is having total value of zero, it should print something like (null) value in it. But why does it hidden from the view? Is there anything wrong to my query?

THanks @!

Comment: what does the inner query return?  (select m.approval_id, own.name, m.decision, count(*) total,        case own.channel           when 'CH1' then 'CH1'           when 'CH2' then 'CH2'           else 'Others Channel'       end the_channel       from tableM m, owner own       where m.decision in ('REJ', 'APP', 'CAN')       and own.id=m.approval_id       group by m.approval_id, staff.staff_name, m.decision, own.channel       order by m.approval_id )

Comment: @forsvarir I have added the output of inner query. It is exactly the same as the parent output.

Comment: whats staff.staff_name in the inner query?

Comment: @Chris Bednarski Thanks for reminding me the typo error, it is own.name, not staff.staff_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to do a cross join between your owner and your code table.
Then you do the left join.

I have modelised 3 table : Type for your 3 lines APP, REJ and CAN, then a user table, equivalent to your owner table, and a third table decision, equivalent to your tableM.

The query looks like this :

```
SELECT c.user_id, c.type_code, COUNT(d.id)
FROM
(

    SELECT t.ID as type_id, u.id as user_id, t.CODE as type_code
    FROM Type t, Userr u
) c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Decision d 
            ON d.user_id = c.user_id
            AND d.type_id = c.type_id
GROUP BY c.user_id, c.type_code
```

Not tested but for yours set of table :

```
select a.id_own, a.code, count(m.approval_id)
from
    (
        select code, own.id as id_own
        from (
          select 'APP' code, '1' seq from dual
          union all
          select 'REJ' code, '2' seq from dual
          union all
          select 'CAN' code, '3' seq from dual
        ) , owner own
    ) a
    left outer join tableM m
on a.code = m.decision
and a.id_own = m.approval_id
group by a.id_own, a.code
order by a.id_own
```

Note that the count(m.approval_id) will give you the number of approval_id that appear not null in the left join.

Comment: Your algorithm just so perfect!! I learnt new technique from You :0)

Answer (score 1):

Your outer join is on code=decision. That means you get one row for each codes which don't occur as decision on the right side. Obviously you want to do your left join with a cross join of 3 codes and all distinct APPROVAL_IDs giving all the combinations of code and APPROVAL_ID on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that

```
group by approval_id, code, total
```

should be

```
group by approval_id, code
```